# Trouble With Keras in R

Tags: keras, r, rstudio

I am using Rstudio on windows 11 trying to install and use keras for deep learning. Following the instructions from the ISLR2 book for installing dependencies (https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/keras-instructions.html) I still get an error when I try to run my code using the keras library. It confirmed that my installation of tensorflow and keras was successful but when I try to run my code I get the following.

Code:

````
library(tensorflow)

library(keras)

library(magrittr)

modnn <- keras_model_sequential() %>%

  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu",
              input_shape = ncol(x))
              layer_dropout(rate=.4) %>%
              layer_dense(units=1)```


Output:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘keras’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'keras', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘keras’ was built under R version 4.3.1 


Any help would be appreciated
````